# Elastic Search compound queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I would to make a compound query in elastic search?
Like a query: co la

And the search results return:

- Coca cola 350ml
- Diet coca cola 2L
- Latin condom ultra soft
- Cornstarch
- Lard

Assuming i have an index "FOOD" and type "AllProducts", how to structure this search?

Thanks

Complementing the requests about mapping the index I used this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost: 9200 / food / _settings' -d' {
             "Index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.0 ":  "standard ",
             "Index.analysis.analyzer.default.tokenizer ":  "standard ",
             "Index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.1 ":  "lowercase ",
             "Index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.2 ":  "stop ",
             "Index.analysis.analyzer.default.filter.3 ": "asciifolding "
} '
```

Example of current search using match_phrase_prefix, but it only allows compound words to have the last sentence as a snippet.

```
This.clientElastic.search ({
      Index: 'food'
      Type: 'AllProdutcts',
      Body: {
        "From": 0, "size": 50,
        Query: {
          Match_phrase_prefix: {
            NameProduct: event.srcElement.value,
            
          }
        }
      }
    }). Then (function (resp) {

      If (event.srcElement.value == "") {
        Send search = null;
      } Else {
        Env.busca = resp.hits.hits;
      }
    }, Function (err) {
      Console.log (err.message);
    });
```

Thanks again

Comment: You need to provide more details: the mapping of the index, the query you already tried and sample documents.

Comment: @AndreiStefan request made! thanks